# Open / Read or Decompile .xpt to idl

Tags: xpcom, idl

I use a firefox addon which makes hidden requests to a website. I already examined the code in all .js .xul and .xpi files. there is only 1 .xpt file (1kb) left where the request must be coded. now i want to open that to examine the code too.

.xpt is afaik a compiled .idl file

1. Can this be done?
2. How?

   Thanks for your wisdom ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An XPT file is a compiled IDL file but it doesn't contain any code - it is merely an interface definition. It defines which properties and methods a component exposes but it doesn't define them - the actual definition of the component has to be in a JavaScript or DLL file. As you aren't mentioning any binary components, the component must be defined in the JavaScript files you already looked at.

In other words: the answer to "Can it be done" is: yes, with sufficient effort. Just looking at the strings contained in the file will already tell you the interfaces defined as well as the property and method names. If you need the parameters/parameter types then you will have to dig deeper. But for your purpose that would be pointless.

Comment: hi Wladimir. thx for your answer. In a xul file there is the request http target written. i thought the .xpt file takes that with a selector to actually make the request. Are you 100% sure that there is no executing possiblity for code insidea a xpt file? packing the addon without this file makes it unusable. Opening the file in notepad++ results in unidentificable code. So no way for me to see whats inside that tiny 1 kb file? thanks

Comment: Yes, 100% sure - it doesn't contain any code. Notepad is probably the worst tool to view binary files, you might want to try [strings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897439) instead. As to the request, without knowing the details: XUL does lots of things "by itself", so maybe there is no additional code.

Comment: Guud to know. just for completeness this is the extension which i was speaking about: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/modify-headers/ . there are 2 xpt files (each 1kb) in the folder "components". it made a get request to a ip with some hashlike parameter. i just wanted to know what this contains. why does open source mozilla let dev's code in such a closed format????? Yeah i know firefox's source is also full of that :)

Comment: @Email: It isn't a closed format. These two files contain `mhIHeader` and `nsIModifyheaders` interfaces. The actual implementation is in the `modifyheaders-service.js` file next to them.

Comment: thx for bringing some light into this. Not lot people are familiar with this format for giving advise to non programmer's.